# What's the purpose of the file "pylab.py"

Tags: python

I looked at the file "pylab.py" at *matplotlab*'s directory and found that it contains a great bunch of `import`s, and then defines a single variable "`bytes`" at the last line. Here is the last several lines of this file:

```
from numpy.fft import *
from numpy.raenter code herendom import *
from numpy.linalg import *

import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

# don't let numpy's datetime hide stdlib
import datetime

# This is needed, or bytes will be numpy.random.bytes from
# "from numpy.random import *" above
bytes = six.moves.builtins.bytes
```

I wonder what's the purpose of such a file when it only defines a seemingly useless variable. As a result, what's the purpose of writing code like `from matplotlib import pylab`?

Comment: to change what `bytes` represents as mentioned in the comment??

Comment: If you want to investigate this further, just add a `print(bytes)` before and after `bytes = six.moves.builtins.bytes`

Answer (score 1):

The `matplotlib` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) say:

> pylab is a convenience module that bulk imports matplotlib.pyplot (for plotting) and numpy (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space. Although many examples use pylab, it is no longer recommended.

So for example, you can do

`>>> from pylab import *`

And you have imported all the names imported by pylab into your local namespace.  This is convenient when using the interactive shell.

Additionally, pylab imports `datetime` and `bytes`.  This is because the `from numpy.foo import *` statements import numpy objects named `bytes` and `datetime` which are not the same as the standard python objects with these names, so they need to be overridden with the standard versions.

The practice of importing names into a module just so other modules can import them from there instead of the original module is not unusual. For example, given this module:

```
$ cat foo/__init__.py
from bar import *
from baz.quux import *
from spam import eggs
```

Other modules can do `from foo import eggs` rather than `from foo.spam import eggs`.  Apart from the convenience of less typing, this approach hides the internal structure of the `foo` package from its clients.  As long as they import from the top level module they need not be concerned that the internal structure of the package may change over time.  This is a form of the [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) design pattern.